# Get Local Object Rotation in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my code, I am limiting rotation about an axes as in this code:

```
if (obj.rotation.x > -0.5) {
    // rotate
}
```

I have matching code to detect < 0.5. This worked until I started rotating the object about another axis, which created a disconnect between local and global space for the object.

I know I can set the object's local rotation with `obj.rotateX(rads)`, but how can I get the local rotation?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can set the object's local rotation with obj.rotateX(rads), but how can I get the local rotation?

`Object3D.rotation` always represents the local rotation, no matter if the object has ancestors or not. It seems to me you are mixing up the concepts of world and local space.

There are various ways to get the world rotation of an object e.g. by extracting it from `Object3D.matrixWorld` or by calling [Object3D.getWorldQuaternion](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldQuaternion).

`three.js R107`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but then how would you extract information from Obect3d.matrixWorld, then?

Comment: You can use for example [Matrix4.decompose()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Matrix4.decompose). This method extracts the position, quaternion and scale components into separate objects.

Comment: How to get degrees for individual axis local rotation ?

Comment: Any suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560735/three-sj-rotation-sending-info-via-network-not-fit?noredirect=1#comment133321728_75560735 ...